# if database query param is not user submitted but from database does it have to escaped?

Tags: mysql

Pretty simple really,

If I pull an array from a database and then use a value from that array, say an auto increment field, do I have to use a prepared statement on that query or will I be safe using a normal sql query as the value cannot change of the variable and I know it will not be a sql injection attack. Same goes for is the variable is set in a session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be safe, if you know that the database is from the trusted source. And that in 99% is.

If you are connecting to foreign (not own) database, which might have some dangerous text in it, only in that case, yes, you must escape the input, otherwise no.

Comment: Ye the database is solely mine, I only ask as before I was preparing queries that only use session variables, but now I can escape that overhead just doing a normal call thanks :)

Comment: Yes, then do not bother escaping, to keep the code fast and clean.